# Toolbar and floating action button are not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, floating-action-button

I want my layout to look like
[this (design preview in Android Studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVjmt.png).

Sadly, when I run the application in debug mode I get the following displayed on my emulator [(just half of the toolbar is visible and the fab not at all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twlLb.jpg).

Also my `Toolbar` is pinned to the top although I applied `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in my `layout.xml` file.

*layout.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_main"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `AppBarLayout`

Comment: the toolbar is fully showing right now but floating action button is still missing thanks in advance @Lamorak

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the toolbar is designed to be "above" every other view. I had the same problem and just added a view below the toolbar to create some space. This allowed the fab to become visible.

Something like:

```
    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>
```